# How do I open settings for Krita

Tags: 18.04, krita

after an update, Krita does not show menu bar. I understand there is a configuration/settings available, but since it would have been on the menu bar, I can't see it.
Is there a CL to open the preferences/configuration/settings?

Comment: With `krita` closed (not running), rename `~/.config/kritarc` to something else and restart `krita`. See if that works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. That step did not help.

Comment: Take a look at https://docs.krita.org/KritaFAQ#Resetting_Krita_configuration

Comment: Maybe I'm asking for the wrong thing. There used to be a panel with text/dropdowns. Like 'select' or 'image,' or 'filters.'  I'm calling that a 'menu bar.' Maybe I still have a 'menu bar.' The only thing on it is a few icons reprenting 'open,' 'save,' 'undo' etc. I'm looking for the drop-down menus.

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. That step did not help. I deleted the file and reopened Krita...same. I uninstalled Krita and searched for and deleted all left-behind files with the name Krita. Reinstalled Krita from the website repository.  Open Krita...same. Opened Kritac and found an entry: MenuBar=Disabled. I changed it to be =Enabled and saved Kritac. Opened Krita...same. Opened Kritac and found the entry MenuBar and found it was again =Disabled

Comment: I uninstalled Krita. Found the 'left-behind' file of Kritac, opened and reset MenuBar to Enabled. Reinstalled Krita. Before opening, I checked Kritac and found the MenuBar=Enabled. Opened Krita and ...same. Opened Kritac and found the MenuBar=Disabled. It had reset to default. I'm lost.

Comment: 'apt policy krita' shows: Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:4.0.3-1~bionic
  Version table:
     2:4.0.3-1~bionic 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:4.0.1+dfsg-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages

Comment: It's `kritarc`, not Kritac. I don't see any mention of "MenuBar" in my `kritarc`. Sorry, I'm out of ideas other than you purge the ppa version and use the regular Krita.

Comment: my mistake. Kritarc is the file I've been working with. I've reinstalled the Ubuntu programs version with the same results. I'd reinstall version 3 if I could figure out how.